# Package built with webpack throws 'Parsing error: Unexpected token =' when installed and run with npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I have 2 projects and I wish to import the first into the second using node.
I am building the first project using webpack and I'm also using typescript with it.

After I build the first project, I then import it into the second project using a file path in the package.json.
However, when I import it into the second project and run it through VueJS, I get the following error:

```
/home/***/dev/git/project_1/dist/index.js
  2:25034  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

The code it refers to is the e=!0 in this text snippet:

```
i.enc.Base64url={stringify:function(t,e=!0){var n=t.words,r=t.sigBytes
```

Here is the config, if this will help:

**Project 1**

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: 'main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'project1',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 200,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: ['**/node_modules', '**/dist'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "package.json" },
        { from: "index.d.ts" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**Project 2**

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "project1": "file:../project_1/dist/",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: In the code example there doesn't seem to be any closing curly braces...

Comment: Where is this error reported? In the browser or during the build process by node?

Comment: The code snippet is only showing the code around the point which it errors (the built file is 267,000 characters long).

It is failing during the build process of the Vue app (project 2)

Comment: Here is more of the code snippet, if helpful: function(t,e=!0){var n=t.words,r=t.sigBytes,i=e?this._safe_map:this._map;t.clamp();for(var a=[],o=0;o<r;o+=3)for(var s=(n[o>>>2]>>>24-o%4*8&255)<<16|(n[o+1>>>2]>>>24-(o+1)%4*8&255)<<8|n[o+2>>>2]>>>24-(o+2)%4*8&255,u=0;u<4&&o+.75*u<r;u++)a.push(i.charAt(s>>>6*(3-u)&63));var c=i.charAt(64);if(c)for(;a.length%4;)a.push(c);return a.join("")}